# C++ - Winsock server receiving distorted buffer

Tags: c++, windows, winsock

I am trying to repetitively send the screen bitmap buffer of a client to a server. The program works perfect when the client and server are running on the same machine, otherwise the server receives a distorted buffer. The distorted buffer received by the server seems to start from a byte which was not the starting byte of a buffer sent by the client (I am not sure). w=1366 and h=768 are the screen width and height respectively of both the server and the client.

Client code:

```
while (connect(sSocket,(sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr))!=0) {}

while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {
    s=4*w*h;
    while (s>0) {
        n=send(sSocket,buf,s,0); s-=n;
        for (i=0; i<s; i++) {buf[i]=buf[i+n];}
    }
    BitBlt(MemDC,0,0,w,h,hdc,0,0,SRCCOPY);
    GetDIBits(MemDC,hBit,0,h,buf,&bmi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
}
```

Server code:

```
do {rSocket=accept(hSocket,(sockaddr*)&addr,&addrlen);}
while (rSocket==INVALID_SOCKET);

while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {
    s=4*w*h; while (s>0) {n=recv(rSocket,buf,s,0); s-=n;}
    SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc,0,0,w,h,0,0,0,h,buf,&bmi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
}
```

I have been changing my code in many ways hoping to get the problem fixed, but it has been two weeks and it is still there. The problem is with such a simple code, yet I couldn't find any post related to it. Thanks in advance.

Just in case the full codes are required, here they are:

Client:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    //INITIALIZATION

    WSADATA wData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wData);
    SOCKET sSocket;
    sockaddr_in addr;
    int addrlen=sizeof(addr);
    ZeroMemory(&addr,sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("192.168.135.2");
    addr.sin_port=htons(6115);
    sSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

    int w=1366, h=768, i, n, s;
    HDC hdc=GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP), MemDC=CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    HBITMAP hBit=CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc,w,h);
    BITMAPINFO bmi;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize=sizeof(BITMAPINFO);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth=w;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight=-h;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes=1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount=32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression=BI_RGB;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage=0;
    char *buf=new char[4*w*h];
    SelectObject(MemDC,hBit);
    BitBlt(MemDC,0,0,w,h,hdc,0,0,SRCCOPY);
    GetDIBits(MemDC,hBit,0,h,buf,&bmi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    //END OF INITIALIZATION

    while (connect(sSocket,(sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr))!=0) {}

    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {
        s=4*w*h;
        while (s>0) {
            n=send(sSocket,buf,s,0); s-=n;
            for (i=0; i<s; i++) {buf[i]=buf[i+n];}
        }
        BitBlt(MemDC,0,0,w,h,hdc,0,0,SRCCOPY);
        GetDIBits(MemDC,hBit,0,h,buf,&bmi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    }

    //CLEANUP

    shutdown(sSocket,SD_SEND);
    closesocket(sSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    delete(buf);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP,hdc);
    DeleteDC(hdc); DeleteDC(MemDC);
    DeleteObject(hBit);
    return 0;

}
```

Server:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    //INITIALIZATION

    WSADATA wData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wData);
    SOCKET hSocket, rSocket;
    sockaddr_in addr;
    int addrlen=sizeof(addr);
    ZeroMemory(&addr,sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port=htons(6115);
    hSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    bind(hSocket,(sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
    listen(hSocket,1);

    int i, n, s, w=1366, h=768;
    char *buf=new char[4*w*h];
    HDC hdc=GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    BITMAPINFO bmi;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize=sizeof(BITMAPINFO);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth=w;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight=-h;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes=1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount=32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression=BI_RGB;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage=0;

    //END OF INITIALIZATION

    do {rSocket=accept(hSocket,(sockaddr*)&addr,&addrlen);}
    while (rSocket==INVALID_SOCKET);

    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {
        s=4*w*h; while (s>0) {n=recv(rSocket,buf,s,0); s-=n;}
        SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc,0,0,w,h,0,0,0,h,buf,&bmi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    }

    //CLEANUP

    delete(buf);
    shutdown(rSocket,SD_RECEIVE);
    closesocket(rSocket);
    shutdown(hSocket,SD_RECEIVE);
    closesocket(hSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP,hdc);
    DeleteDC(hdc);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Take a good look at both your 'while (s > 0)' loops. They don't do what you think.

Comment: @EJP Hmm.. the sending end looks like some nasty data-shuffling-down thing.  recv() end seems to be overwriting buf on each loop.

Comment: @Martin James are you talking about the while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESC)) loop? If so what can I do to prevent this overwriting?